# Hermitian transformation and its minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, hermitian-matrices

I have some doubts with this exercise, I think this is due to my problems understanding minimal polynomials. I think I'm a bit confused trying to understand what the statement really wants.

If $T$ is a linear transformation over a complex inner space. Prove that if $T$ is hermitian, then the linear factors of minimal polynomial of $T$ are distinct.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you aware of the spectral theorem?

Comment: The exercise is asking you to show that if we write the minimal polynomial in the form $m(x) = (x - \lambda_1)^{p_1} \cdots (x - \lambda_k)^{p_k}$ with $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ distinct, then it holds that $p_j = 1$ for all $j = 1,\dots,k$.

Comment: Yes, if T is hermitian then is diagonalizable and moreover every eigenvalue is real. Right?

Comment: That's right. Are you aware about the connection between the connection between diagonalizability and the minimal polynomial?

Comment: I know T is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial splits. But with this I can conclude my proof?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “the minimal polynomial splits”?

Comment: I see... It means that every factor is lineal.. But this minimal polynomial must divides the characteristic polynomial, right? I have a question, why is relevant the field of complex?

Comment: I'm not sure what the characteristic polynomial has to do with this. Regarding your question, "Hermitian" is only a valid descriptor for maps over a complex inner product space.

Comment: Get it. Ok... so basically the statement is proved, right?

Comment: Yes. The steps are all here, you just need to put them together

Comment: Thanks, your help means a lot for me.